# Vundle not installing plugins correctly

Tags: vim, archlinux, vundle

I'm running Arch and I'm trying to use Vundle to install plugins.

Here's my ~/.vimrc

```
filetype off
set nocompatible

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'    

Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'
Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript'

call vundle#end()

filetype plugin indent  on      " Treba nam da Vim prepoznaje filetype
syntax on                       " Uključujemo syntax highlighting

set tabstop=4                   " Broj razmaka koji tab stavlja
set shiftwidth=4                " Razmaci za autoindent
set autoindent                  " Auto indent!

set expandtab                   " Stavlja razmake umjesto taba
set smarttab                    " Dodatna carolija

set number                      " Line numbers!

set showmatch                   " Kada je zagrada umetnuta, na sekundu
                                " skoči do njenog para.

set ruler                       " Pokazuje Line/column brojeve

set background=dark             " Lepo tamno bre
```

Now when I run `vim +PluginInstall +qall` it only seems to install VundleVim/Vundle.vim. But when I `:so ~/.vimrc` and reinstall it does it correctly, but the plugins never show up.

`:set rtp` also displays all the paths to `~/.vim/bundle` but they still don't show up. I've tried reinstalling vim, but to no avail. What should I do?

**Edit #1:** Updated `~/.vimrc` to include VundleVim/Vundle.vim.

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Vundle README](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/blob/master/README.md#quick-start), before any other plugins, you have to let Vundle manage itself:

```
" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
```

Comment: Then run `:VundleInstall`

Comment: Not working. I tried running vim both normally and as root, sourced to `~/.vimrc` both times, ran `:VundleInstall`, `:PluginInstall` and `:PluginInstall!`, but it's still not working. Every time it installs only VundleVim/Vundle.vim.

Comment: You installed Vundle with something akin to `git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim`, correct?

Comment: Yes I did. Tried completely reinstalling Vim, no luck.

Comment: What does running `:VundleInstall` tell you?

Comment: `" Installing plugins to /home/tefached/.vim/bundle
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'`
And that's it. It **is** successful, however.

Comment: And you still can't run `:NERDTree`, for example? Your `~/.vim/bundle/` folder is still empty aside from a `Vundle.vim` folder?

Comment: I got it working somehow, after a third reinstall it seems to be functioning now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: For anyone else who comes across, delete the `.vim` directory. If deleting from the command line, delete with `$ rm -Rf ~/.vim` or wherever that `.vim` folder is, then follow the instructions from `https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim` From step 2-4, assuming you already have git installed, and the default directory being the one mentioned in step 1

Comment: Deleting .vim and cloning the git project worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Typing `:VundleInstall` worked for me. I spent a long time doing `:PluginInstall`, but I think once you have `Vundle` installed (you can check by typing `:PluginList`), you can do `:VundleInstall`

Comment: This worked for me in the sense that it exposed that VIM having problems with the github.com connections.

Answer (score 0):

I have the error E117 when I exec `PluginInstall`,because 'set rtp' is not work, the solution is move the `runtime! debian.vim`commond to the top of the .vimrc